# Why my website showing in lower case in google serp?

Tags: google, search-results, meta-tags, technical-seo, title-attribute

My website is focused on custom logo neon signs and meta title optimize with capital letter. When users search for "custom logo neon sign," I have noticed that the title of my website in the search results is displayed in all lowercase letters, which is not consistent with the intended capitalization. The desired title should be "Custom Logo Neon Sign."

I understand that Google's search algorithm has its own way of determining how to display titles, but I would like to ensure that my website title is presented as intended, with proper capitalization.

I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide guidance on how to rectify this issue and have my website title appear correctly in the SERP. Any insights, recommendations, or best practices you can offer to ensure the correct capitalization would be invaluable to me as a website owner.

Comment: Just like the other question, you have the phrase in all caps on your page.

Comment: you mean i should change all heading into capital instead of upper case?

Comment: we are using upper case on the page [neon sign maker](https://createneon.com/create-custom-neon-sign/), and SERP working fine bro.